# Display loading page on wait for response from controller

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring

What is the best attitude to display an animated loading page when waiting for an actual response from controller?

The controller takes quite some time to give a response and I want to display a gif in between. So far I have tried 3 solutions:

1) Display gif on window load -> doesn't solve anything as page loading itself is very short and it starts only after you get a response from controller.

2) Display gif on submit button to redirect to another page -> displays gif nicely but it doesn't animate.

3) Check referer of the request and if it's different than the page itself, then redirect to loading page which immediately after loading itself redirects to desired page. Here animation sometimes occurs but stops before the next page is loaded entirely.

Is there another approach for that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Assuming this is done via a standard page redirection and not AJAX, there's nothing you can do. There is no DOM loaded for you to amend between requests. This is why your second approach shows the loading gif, then immediately unloads it. An alternative solution would be to load the new page, then call your length controller action via AJAX.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you for your reply! I'll check it out!